# How to use fgetl in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand how I can use `fgetl` to read from a file. Here is a sample `.txt` file:

```
0: 2.14 +++ 1.70 +++ 1.57, 28.2
1: 1.20 +++ 1.44 +++ 2.97, 28.6
2: 1.47 +++ 2.32 +++ 4.01, 29.1
3: 1.41 +++ 4.58 +++ 2.95, 29.0
4: 0.33 +++ 1.28 +++ 0.41, 28.8
5: 0.04 +++ 1.07 +++ 0.00, 28.6
6: 0.03 +++ 1.07 +++ 0.00, 28.4
7: 0.03 +++ 1.07 +++ 0.00, 28.1
8: 0.03 +++ 1.08 +++ 0.00, 27.9
9: 0.03 +++ 1.07 +++ 0.00, 27.8
10: 0.04 +++ 1.07 +++ 0.00, 27.6
```

and here is my code:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');

tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    A=sscanf(tline,'%d: %f +++ %f +++ %f, %f');
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

But it does not work (it is obvious that I have no idea what I am doing). I want matrix A to be like this:

```
0 2.14 1.70 1.57 28.2
1 1.20 1.44 2.97 28.6
...
```

Please note that I can do this using some other methods but the point of this question is that I need to understand how to do this using `fgetl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it pretty much all worked out. What you are missing is an index to store the output of every call to `sscanf` and that's it.

Doing so, here is what I get:

```
clear
clc


fid = fopen('Mymatrix.txt');

tline = fgetl(fid);

%// Initialize counter
k = 1;
while ischar(tline)

%// Store in a cell array, just in case the outputs are of different size.
    A{k}=sscanf(tline,'%d: %f +++ %f +++ %f, %f');
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    k = k+1;
end

%// Convert to numeric array. This part would need some tuning if the outputs were of different size

A = cell2mat(A).'

fclose(fid);
```

And the final output looks like this:

```
A =

         0    2.1400    1.7000    1.5700   28.2000
    1.0000    1.2000    1.4400    2.9700   28.6000
    2.0000    1.4700    2.3200    4.0100   29.1000
    3.0000    1.4100    4.5800    2.9500   29.0000
    4.0000    0.3300    1.2800    0.4100   28.8000
    5.0000    0.0400    1.0700         0   28.6000
    6.0000    0.0300    1.0700         0   28.4000
    7.0000    0.0300    1.0700         0   28.1000
    8.0000    0.0300    1.0800         0   27.9000
    9.0000    0.0300    1.0700         0   27.8000
   10.0000    0.0400    1.0700         0   27.6000
```